# use emplace instead of construct object before

Tags: c++, c++11, queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Time {
    int h;
    int m;
    int s;
};

class CompareTime {
public:
    bool operator() (Time& t1, Time& t2) {
        if (t1.h < t2.h) return true;
        if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m < t2.m) return true;
        if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m == t2.m && t1.s < t2.s) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, CompareTime> pq;
    pq.emplace(3,2,40);
    pq.emplace(3,2,26);
    pq.emplace(5,16,13);
    pq.emplace(5,14,20);

    while(!pq.empty()) {
        Time t2 = pq.top();
        cout << setw(4) << t2.h << " " << setw(3) << t2.m << " " << setw(3) <<
            t2.s << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I try to use emplace instead of construct object before.
but got errors such as:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/new_allocator.h: In member function âvoid __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = int, int, int, _Tp = Time]â:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc:95:   instantiated from âvoid std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = int, int, int, _Tp = Time, _Alloc = std::allocator<Time>]â
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_queue.h:527:   instantiated from âvoid std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::emplace(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = int, int, int, _Tp = Time, _Sequence = std::vector<Time, std::allocator<Time> >, _Compare = CompareTime]â
time_queue_test.cpp:25:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:111: error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:111: error: no matching function for call to âTime::Time(int)â
time_queue_test.cpp:7: note: candidates are: Time::Time()
time_queue_test.cpp:7: note:                 Time::Time(const Time&)
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:69,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/queue:62,
                 from time_queue_test.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc: In member function âvoid std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = int, int, int, _Tp = Time, _Alloc = std::allocator<Time>]â:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc:100:   instantiated from âvoid std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = int, int, int, _Tp = Time, _Alloc = std::allocator<Time>]â
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_queue.h:527:   instantiated from âvoid std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::emplace(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = int, int, int, _Tp = Time, _Sequence = std::vector<Time, std::allocator<Time> >, _Compare = CompareTime]â
time_queue_test.cpp:25:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc:314: error: no matching function for call to âTime::Time(int, int, int)â
time_queue_test.cpp:7: note: candidates are: Time::Time()
time_queue_test.cpp:7: note:                 Time::Time(const Time&)
```

Don't know where did I do wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Make your comparator take `const` references. And make it `const`: `bool operator() (const Time& t1, const Time& t2) const`

Comment: `emplace*` doesn't support aggregate initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor that receive the 3 int and initialize the members, is not generated automatically, need to be implemented.

```
struct Time {
    int h;
    int m;
    int s;

    Time(int hv, int mv, int sv)
      : h(hv), m(mv), s(sv)
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**Two issues:**

1. Basically, your type needs to support the following, which your `Time` type doesn't. To fix it, you should include the appropriate 3 argument constructor.

   ```
   new Time(3, 2, 40);
   ```
2. Your comparator should be more `const`:

   ```
   bool operator() (Time const & t1, Time const & t2) const {
   ```

Comment: @JamesKanze: As far as I know, it shouldn't. `class Time` doesn't have a constructor that I can see that takes a `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: @JamesKanze `{ }` is a non-deduced context so `emplace` will never work with that. `pq.push({3, 2, 40});` [does work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fb7fd6602cffa5b) using aggregate initialization.

Comment: To tell the truth, I wasn't even sure whether the syntax would be legal.  But you're right, of course: it's the classical circular problem: in order to resolve the type of the argument, the compiler needs to know the type of the parameter, but in order to know the type of the parameter, it needs to do type deduction based on the type of the argument.  (That's not the way the standard explains it, but that's the real problem.)  And you meant `pq.push_back( {3, 2, 40} );`, didn't you?

Comment: @sharth `{ 3, 2, 40 }` isn't necessarily an `std::initializer_list`.  It's the universal initializer syntax, and can mean almost anything (more or less).  As T.C. points out, the problem here is that the compiler cannot deduce what it is supposed to mean from the context.

Comment: @JamesKanze `priority_queue`s don't have `push_back`. They have `push`.

Comment: @T.C I should have noticed that (especially as I wrote `pq.emplace`, rather than `emplace_back`).